# Which of the following is the highest value?

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers, number-systems

**Question**:

> Find the highest value among $12^9$, $10^{11}$ and $11^{10}$.

I have seen problems like this, but they had surds, these are integers. Also, the LCM of $10$, $11$, $9$ $(990)$ is fairly large to alow a normal approach. There must be some other approach. I know this must be fairly simple, but I am not getting it.

Please show me the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the binomial theorem, perhaps:

$12^9=(11+1)^9= \dots$,

$11^{10}=(10+1)^{10}=\dots$

Comment: [This](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/binomial-theorem.html) ? Pretty confusing to me on how would i go about expanding the `9`-th power of a binomial. please explain a bit more.

Comment: $12^9=11^9+\binom 98 11^8+\binom 97 11^7 + \binom 96 11^6 +\dots$ - just calculate some of the coefficients and you will see what is happening.

Comment: ok, after a lot of research. I finally got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x\ln(21-x)$ for $8\le x\le 13$, $$f'(x)=\ln(21-x)-\frac{x}{21-x}=\frac{(21-x)\ln(21-x)-x}{21-x},\quad\quad\quad 8< x< 13$$
Observe $8\le 21-x \le 13 \Longrightarrow 2<\ln 8\le \ln(21-x) \le \ln 13<4$, then $$16<(21-x)\ln(21-x)<52,\quad\quad\quad 8\le x\le 13$$ 
In particular $f'(x)>0$ for $8< x< 13$, what means $f$ is increasing in $]8,13[$, thus
\begin{align}
f(9)& < &f(10) & < & f(11)\\
9\ln(12)& < &10\ln(11) & < & 11\ln(10)\\
\exp[9\ln(12]& < &\exp[10\ln(11)] & < & \exp[11\ln(10)]
\end{align}
Therefore $12^9<11^{10}<10^{11}$.

Comment: +1 thanks for new approach. Though, could you please direct me to a guide/tutorial on this `In` operator ?? Thanks!